# Browser history with iframe and angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, iframe, browser-history

I got a page that displays external content in a iframe. The content is displaying fine, but when the content of the iframe is loaded another copy of the current page is added to browser history. This causes issues with the browser back button functionality.

I get the path to the content depending on a selected language and then get a path from a resource token.

iframe

```
<iframe ng-if="path" style="height: 90%; background-color: transparent" allowtransparency="true" class="w-full" ng-src="{{path}}" name="storyFrame" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

path loading

```
$http.get(LRM.getUrl('scormToken', scope.selectedLang.scorm_package.resource_token))
    .success(function (response) {
        scope.path =  response;
    }).error(function (response) {
        toaster.pop('error', '', 'Could not fetch scorm package');
    });
```

The question is,how do i load iframe content without adding to browser history?

Answer (score 1):

Try to use

```
scope.path = $sce.trustAsResourceUrl(response)
```

and include $sce in controller.
Im not sure on this, but i know angular sometimes has problems with ng-src and iframes

EDIT:

I found out now that my iFrame is acting same as your, i added new variable, lets call it showIframe, before i change src i set it to false and after i change src set this to true (in timeout without ms number - auto), so i frame is removed and added to DOM and history is not changed.

Comment: Same result, it's not that the iframe is not loading, it's that it places a new page in browser history once src is changed.

Comment: Think the browser watch for all src changes and save in history, this way whole iframe is removed and added again in DOM. This will work only with ng-if which u are already using